# ParseSDK: Why file_get_contents() returns “failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!”?

Tags: php, database, curl, parse-platform, file-get-contents

I am having a problem updating an object in my Parse Cloud DB...

Basically I run the code

```
include_once '../lib/libraries/Parse/autoload.php';    
use Parse\ParseClient;    
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseObject;
ParseClient::initialize('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

$query = new ParseQuery("_User");
$query->equalTo("username", $_COOKIE["username"]);
$user = $query->first();
$user->set("plan", "entrepreneur");
$user->save();
```

I then get this:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/byMcqe93lC):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in /Volumes/Transcend/Google
>   Drive/Projects/Applandr/lib/libraries/Parse/ParseClient.php on line
>   240
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /Volumes/Transcend/Google
>   Drive/Projects/Applandr/lib/libraries/Parse/ParseObject.php on line
>   528

I have made sure `allow_url_fopen = On` is set, and have not tried cURL as it is actually a Parse class that is attempting to get the contents of the URL.

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Can somebody please help me, all I want to do is update an object in my Parse DB.